# What is the syntax of Firebase notification

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to write the firebase notification as a String like JSON format .. I already sent the notification for one device but when trying to send to **multiple devices** i got bad request ..

```
params = new StringEntity("{\n" +
"    \"to\" : \"ds1YTh...UUZOos\",\n" +
"    \"notification\" : {\n" +
"      \"body\" : \""+jobTitle+"\",\n" +
"      \"title\" : \"New Job!\",\n" +
"      \"icon\" : \"hire\"\n" +
"      \"sound\" : \"default\"\n"+
"       \"time_to_live\" : "+3600+
"    }\n" +
"     \"data\": {"+
"     }"+
" }");
```

how could i do that .. and if I can't do it this way what is the best way to implement this .. I'm using **HttpClient** and **HttpPost** and primefaces 5.3

Comment: You're using `to` but you intend to send to multiple devices. Have you tried using `registration_ids`? See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39547590/4625829).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a few relevant links:

- [Sending notifications to multiple devices not subscribed to a certain topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771514/sending-notifications-to-multiple-devices-not-subscribed-to-a-certain-topic)
- the [Firebase documentation on sending downstream messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json)
- the [Firebase documentation on sending to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) (which covers using topics and device groups)
- [FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Send to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547277/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-send-to-multiple-devices)

But if you want to stick closest to your current code, you should be able to specify the device tokens in a `registration_ids` property:

```
params = new StringEntity("{\n" +
"    \"registration_ids\" : [\"ds1YTh...UUZOos\", \"et2ZUi...VVUPpt\"],\n" +
"    \"notification\" : {\n" +
"      \"body\" : \""+jobTitle+"\",\n" +
"      \"title\" : \"New Job!\",\n" +
"      \"icon\" : \"hire\"\n" +
"      \"sound\" : \"default\"\n"+
"       \"time_to_live\" : "+3600+
"    }\n" +
"     \"data\": {"+
"     }"+
" }");
```

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much @Frank van Puffelen this perfectly working :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in Asp.net I hope it will help in some way...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count (No. of Rows or Device); i++)
            {
 tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data1 = new
            {
               to="" + DeviceID + "",
               priority="high",
                notification = new
                  {
                      body = Message,
                      is_background = true,
                      title = Heading,
                      appicon = "http://webbestsites.com/images/1_icon.png",
                      sound = "default"
                  },
  }
```