# C# Send notification to device group with unique custom data FCM

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am aware that I can supply `registration_ids` to the JSON request to send to multiple devices in the form of string arrays. However, I have a unique token that I want to send to each of those `registration_ids`. How can I achieve that without simply looping the send request for the number of devices I wish to send to:

```
registration_ids: [1,2,3,4,5]
data: {
  //if id==1, include the necessary token I wish to include.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if you are attempting to send something unique to each user, you'll have to send each unique payload separately.

What I can think of (just assuming a scenario) is for you to send a specific parameter (an ID of some sort) and have the client app interpret it depending on the user. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Interesting idea: mail merge in FCM messages. :-)

Comment: I thought similarly. Luckily that token is just basically a handshake for me to continue to perform another simple action so I suppose I shall take FCM's success response as a handshake for now.