# Is it possible to send batch notifications with subscriptions ids having different fields?

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I have this code for batch:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$google_gcm_url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$title = 'Title';
$msg = 'Message';

// just sample unrealistic ids
$fields['to'] = array ( 
    'mobileSubscriptionId1',
    'mobileSubscriptionId2', 
    'mobileSubscriptionId3'
); 

$fields['notification'] = array (
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $msg,
    // 'url' => 'some_url1',
    'url' => array (
        'some_url1', 
        'some_url2', 
        'some_url3'
    )
);

$fields['priority'] = 'high';
$fields['content_available'] = true;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $google_gcm_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Is it possible to set the subcription "mobileSubscriptionId1" so when they click it it will go to the first url field "some_url1"? 
Then "mobileSubscriptionId2" to "some_url2" , then "mobileSubscriptionId3" to "some_url3" .
I've tried my code but it doesn't work.
I don't want to loop through curl because it's really slow.
Realistically I have thousands of ids.

Comment: So this is being sent to a mobile app and the user is expected to click on a link and to return to the provided url? Maybe you should use one url, and get the mobile app to provide a unique identifier (GCM registrationID maybe?), lookup the user, and handle the requested accordingly. GCM supports batches, and 1000 seems to be recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Send notification to device group with unique custom data FCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755955/c-sharp-send-notification-to-device-group-with-unique-custom-data-fcm)

Comment: @markdwhite Might do this if I have the onclick handler for mobile but the bad thing is it's a third party that created our mobile app :( , This is a similar approach to my desktop notification. Might come up with an idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible for GCM (and FCM). If you intend to send uniques payloads for each user, you'll have to send a separate request for each. (See my answer in the possible duplicate post).

@markdwhite's comment seems to be feasible.

Comment: Thanks! Might do an alternative, like running in a background unnoticed using.