# What are some restrictions that Google has to prevents a push notification from being shown to the user that we should know about?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What are some restrictions that Google has to prevents a push notification from being shown to the user that we should know about?

I tried sending 80K pushes at once, and Google either

Automatically revokes the push token or queues up the push and doesn’t display it to the user

i'm using FCM

Comment: 80K.. Those are rookie numbers, you gotta pump those numbers up.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any official documentation that states any mind of restrictions for the push notifications from FCM, other than the [Message Payload size limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), the [`DeviceMessageRateExceeded`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) error (kinda similar to [Throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39652615/4625829), which AFAIK is no longer applied) possibly only for iOS, and `TopicsMessageRateExceeded` error to avoid spamming when sending to topics.

Other possibilities for a message not showing up could be because of the device(s) itself (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/4625829)).