# How to send a notification to an over 5000 users using Firebase?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, multiple-users

I would like to send a notification to all the users in a system. I'm using Laravel framework. I believe there is a limit to the number of tokens a notification could be sent to.
Could you please help me find a solution to send the notification to users which might exceed 10,000? And what is the threshold of tokens that can be sent at a time?

Comment: use laravel queue for sending notification to large number of user, i have tried to send almost 7000 users read notification document, important tip try to use redis for queue don't use mysql or sqlite for queue it will lock your jobs table due to high delete and update records

Comment: Any code that might help me get the first steps done?

Comment: I would recommend subscribing the devices to a topic and sending one notification to the topic instead. This has the advantage that you can let Firebase handle the delivery, and that you don't need your own application to do the chunking and sending of all the messages (and it saves you quite some requests). Using the Firebase REST API, you can send a message to 500 devices per request.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658639/5292292) to answer your question on threshold limits.

If you dont want to manage your own infra for sending notifications, check https://ravenapp.dev . It provides a simple API to send any kind of and volume of notifications without writing any code.